# Constraining a polynomial function

Tags: polynomials

Suppose I have a polynomial of the following form, 
$$f(x)=\frac{a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+\cdots+a_nx^n}{b_1x+b_2x^2+b_3x^3+\cdots+b_nx^n}$$
What constraints shall be put on the coefficients and $x$'s so when plotting $f(x)$:

1. The line starts above 1.
2. If starts below one at some point it goes over 1.

Note coefficients are $a$'s and $b$'s are positive integers.

About point (1) I think the only condition required for $f(x)$ to start above 1 is that $a_1>b_1$?

Comment: I would interpret the conditions as

1. $f(0)>1$ or $f(0) \geq 1$; and

2. $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x) > 1$.

Am I correct?

Comment: $f$ is not a polynomial!  It is a rational function.

Comment: Strictly speaking $f(x)$ is not defined at $x=0$, although you can "fill the gap" in a continuous way by defining $f(0)=\frac{a_1}{b_1}$.

Comment: @MattiP. yes 1. $f(0)>1$ and 2. $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}f(x)>1$

Comment: @user10354138 Thanks for the heads up

Comment: With this help, can you solve the problem yourself? You literally have just plug in the values and take into account @gandalf61's comment.